# Came across this code snippet while looking for an elegant and pythonic answer to a problem

Tags: python

While solving a question from a problem set. I came across code that is more elegant than mine but I'm having trouble understanding it. The problem is to check for plates. While I made separate functions for each check. The code below seems to do it in very few lines. The minimalist in me wants to understand what the code is doing. Specifically the intent behind the divide variable.

```
    def main():
        plate = input("Plate: ")
        if is_valid(plate):
            print("Valid")
        else:
            print("Invalid")
    
    
    def is_valid(s):
        if 1 < len(s) <= 6 and s[:2].isalpha() and s.isalnum():
            divide = [s[:len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2:]] 
    
    
            if divide[1][0] == '0':   
                return False
            else:
                return True
    
    
    
    main()
```

I'm having trouble understanding what the divide variable is doing.

I have solved the problem but was looking for pythonic solution to it when I came across this snippet.
Here's a link to the problem : https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/2/plates/

Comment: That code does not fulfil the brief. Specifically it shows that AAA22A is valid whereas it is not (according to the rules of the challenge). So, rather than worry about what *divide* is doing, you should review the algorithm

Comment: Hi! Could you edit your question to contain at least the requirements for your code, so we don't need to check an off-site link?

Comment: Even if this were a correct solution to the problem, it's overly complicated (and therefore not Pythonic IMO). There's no reason to produce the whole `divide` list, when no part of it other than `divide[1][0]` is used. `divide[1][0]` can simply be replaced by `s[len(s)//2]`. (But, as has been said, the original code is not a correct solution anyway.)

Comment: Thanks @DarkKnight, I was so swept in by the compact-ability of the code that I forgot to test all cases.

Comment: Sorry @Hoodlum, I'll keep it in mind for future questions.

Comment: You're right @slothrop, I'll stick with creating a function for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*divide* is a list comprised of two strings which are the two halves of some other string.

This would be precisely correct is the original string had an even length. However, if the original has an odd number of characters this is not the case. Specifically, the first item in the list would be one character shorter than the second.

For example:

```
s = 'abc123'
divide = [s[:len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2:]]
print(divide)
```

**Output:**

```
['abc', '123']
```

...whereas...

```
s = 'abc1234'
divide = [s[:len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2:]]
print(divide)
```

**Output:**

```
['abc', '1234']
```

Why this is being done in the context of the brief is a mystery. It serves no purpose.

It's easier to break down the rules into simple, discrete steps. Something like this:

```
def is_valid(p):
    if (lp := len(p)) < 2 or lp > 6:
        return False # invalid length
    if not p.isalnum():
        return False # not all alphanumeric
    if not p[:2].isalpha():
        return False # first two characters not alphabetic
    # start search for first decimal digit (if there is one)
    for i in range(2, len(p)):
        if p[i].isdecimal():
            try:
                # validate by trying to convert remainder of plate string to an integer
                int(p[i:])
                # OK - so there was no exception but first number may have been zero
                return p[i] != '0'
            except ValueError:
                return False
    # there were no digits in the plate string
    return True
```